# Delete datetime from SQL database based on hour

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, sql-delete

I'm a python dev, I'm handling an SQL database through sqlite3 and I need to perform a certain SQL query to delete data.
I have tables which contain datetime objects as keys.
I want to keep only one row per hour (the last record for that specific time) and delete the rest.
I also need this to only happen on data older than 1 week.

Here's my attempt:

```
import sqlite3
c= db.cursor()
c.execute('''DELETE FROM TICKER_AAPL WHERE time < 2022-07-11 AND time NOT IN
    ( SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT min(time) FROM TICKER_AAPL GROUP BY hour(time)) AS temp_tab);''')
```

Here's a screenshot of the table itself:

[image: Table example]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the format of your dates from `yyyyMMdd ...` to `yyyy-MM-dd ...`, because this is the only valid text date format for SQLite.

Then use the function strftime() in your query to get the hour of each value in the column `time`:

```
DELETE FROM TICKER_AAPL 
WHERE time < date(CURRENT_DATE, '-7 day') 
  AND time NOT IN (SELECT MAX(time) FROM TICKER_AAPL GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', time));
```

Comment: I think the last record for that specific time means `NOT IN (SELECT MAX(time) FROM TICKER_AAPL GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', time))`

Comment: @FrankHe correct, *last* should be MAX. I wonder why the OP's query contains MIN